# Unity C# Raycasting in front of enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hi I have script that shoud send raycast in front of object ... but instead it sends raycast ALWAYS into the same place ... no idea why

here is the code:

```
//Send raycast to imitate enemy sight
void SendRaycast() {
    //Start and end point of raycasts
    Vector3 startPosition = transform.position;
    Vector3 targetPosition = Vector3.zero;

    //Start and end angle of raycasts
    int startAngle = (int)(-angle * 0.5F);  // half the angle to the Left of the forward
    int finishAngle = (int)(angle * 0.5F); // ..... and to the Right

    int inc = (int)( angle / 10 );

    //raycast that we are going to 'send'
    RaycastHit hit;

    // step through and find each target point
    for(int i = startAngle; i < finishAngle; i += inc ) // Angle from forward
    {
        targetPosition = (Quaternion.Euler( 0, i, 0 ) * transform.forward ).normalized * 5.0f;
        //targetPosition = transform.forward;

        // linecast between points
        if ( Physics.Linecast( startPosition, targetPosition, out hit ) )
        {
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
                chase = true;
                Debug.Log("See Player");
            }
        }           
        // to show ray just for testing
        Debug.DrawLine( startPosition, targetPosition, Color.green );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just tried out your code and it works ok as long as the local z direction of the object is orthogonal to the world Y direction. If they are colinear, all rays overlap. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have top down view with XZ , i want the enemy to look forward and when he sees player well chase him :) but probably messed somethind with coordinates

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/704934/raycast-enemy-does-not-look-forward-but-into-the-s.html

here i added image showing my problem ... dont have enough rep on stack :P